# How to change UIButton image with if statements

Tags: swift, uibutton

I want to change a button's background. This is a levels view controller that changes the button's background if the level has been unlocked

I have looked at other solutions on Stackoverflow but none seem to work.

```
class levels: UIViewController {
    //Level's state
    var level2Unlocked: Bool = true
    var level3Unlocked: Bool = false
    var level4Unlocked: Bool = false
    var level5Unlocked: Bool = false

    //Levels buttons
    @IBOutlet weak var level2Locked: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var level3Locked: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var level4Locked: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var level5Locked: UIButton!

    //Switch button image if the level is unlocked
    func levelLocked() {
        if level2Unlocked == true {
            level2Locked.setImage(UIImage(named: "leve2"), for:.normal)
        }
    }
```

If the level2Unlocked = true, then the background image for Level2Locked button should change to level2 image.

Comment: How are you calling `levelLocked()`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is how you call functions but I'm calling levelLocked() in the viewDidLoad() function.

Comment: If the keep in mind if the image is not a png then you have pass the extension in the name as well like `UIImage(named: "level2.jpg")` otherwise your code should work.

Comment: You can check directly image of button like this -> 
YourButton.backgroundImage(for: .normal) == UIimage("imagename.jpg")

Comment: I took a look at the image's file and it is a png. Any other reasons why the code shouldn't work?

Comment: YourButton.backgroundImage(for: .normal) == UIimage("imagename.jpg") Doesn't seem to make it work

Comment: Try to make background different color so at least you can understand the problem is about the image etc. Also can you give us the full VC ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't know what the problem was but I tried moving the if statement into another function. I moved it in the viewDidLoad function and it works now.